# How to get local node identity to show when starting a new Substrate node?

Tags: substrate-node-template, identity

Why isn't the local node identity showing when I start a new Substrate node?

I'm using this command:

```
./target/release/node-template \
--base-path /tmp/alice \
--chain local \
--alice \
--port 30333 \
--ws-port 9945 \
--rpc-port 9933 \
--node-key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 \
--telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
--validator
```

And would expect the output to look more like this:

```
2021-03-10 17:34:27  Substrate Node
2021-03-10 17:34:27  ✌️  version 3.0.0-1c5b984-x86_64-linux-gnu
2021-03-10 17:34:27  ❤️  by Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>, 2017-2021
2021-03-10 17:34:27   Chain specification: Local Testnet
2021-03-10 17:34:27   Node name: Alice
2021-03-10 17:34:27   Role: AUTHORITY
2021-03-10 17:34:27   Database: RocksDb at /tmp/alice/chains/local_testnet/db
2021-03-10 17:34:27  ⛓  Native runtime: node-template-100 (node-template-1.tx1.au1)
2021-03-10 17:34:27   Initializing Genesis block/state (state: 0xea47…9ba8, header-hash: 0x9d07…7cce)
2021-03-10 17:34:27   Loading GRANDPA authority set from genesis on what appears to be first startup.
2021-03-10 17:34:27  ⏱  Loaded block-time = 6000 milliseconds from genesis on first-launch
2021-03-10 17:34:27  Using default protocol ID "sup" because none is configured in the chain specs
2021-03-10 17:34:27   Local node identity is: 12D3KooWEyoppNCUx8Yx66oV9fJnriXwCcXwDDUA2kj6vnc6iDEp
...
```

But my response looks more like this:
[image: same response but missing a bunch of info…]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a version of Substrate with a known bug that has been fixed. Here you can check 2 issues about your problem:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/11855
- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/11691

For now, you can either pin the `tracing-core` crate to version `0.1.26`, or you can update the dependencies to remove the bugged feature, as a temporary workaround, like here:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11854

Comment: I've tried using `cargo update -p tracing-core --precise 0.1.26` but I'm getting this error:

`error: failed to select a version for the requirement \`tracing-core = "^0.1.27"\`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.1.26`
Any idea why or how to fix it?

Comment: Also, I'm not exactly sure what "pinning" a crate to a version is or how to do it.

Comment: Point your substrate dependencies to a commit after these ones: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11854/files and it should work for you. By the way, "pinning" means forcing cargo to use a specific version of a crate.

Comment: And I'd do that by changing the Cargo.toml in `/release`, is that right? I can't seem to find a "tracing-core" dependency there.

Comment: You have to change the Cargo.toml of all dependencies. Change all them, the substrate ones.

Comment: @afm Do we need to re-build the substrate-node-template after updating the dependencies? I found this package to update the dependencies. https://clearloop.github.io/sup/